# C++\GLUT window menu bar

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glut

I am writing a simple glut Application, and my teacher wants me to create a top menu bar, as in any windows app(you know, file\edit etc, the ruler on the window's top).

I looked in glut documentation and googled, all I can find is a popup menu that opens with mouse's right button - not what was defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLUT library provide service like creating window, callback functions, timer, mouse event and key press. But you want to make window menu bar for which GLUT does not provide the built in function. GLUT is useful for game , simulation not for GUI. For that you have to use the GUI library. Here are the best list of GUI library

1. [FLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fltk/info)
2. [GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gtk/info)
3. [QT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info)

Among them I suggest you to use QT because QT is also object-oriented suitable with C++. With the help of [qt-creator](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt-creator/info) you can make GUI by drag and drop in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Crazy Eddie's GUI System](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which supports [Menu & Popup](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Menu_and_Popup)

> Crazy Eddie's GUI System is a free library providing windowing and
>   widgets for graphics APIs / engines where such functionality is not
>   natively available, or severely lacking. The library is object
>   orientated, written in C++, and targeted at games developers who
>   should be spending their time creating great games, not building GUI
>   sub-systems!

Comment: i downloaded his library, and it doesn't contain all the core files like cegui.h, that his programs require...

Comment: Did you tried [this link](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/CEGUI_Downloads_0.7.8).  Download _CEGUI 0.7.8 Binary Dependency Downloads for MSVC++_ files.

Comment: yes, from there. i even downloaded its dependencies. LOL, seems like he forgot to actually put HIS code inside....:)

Comment: may be, i dont know, do u? *if i knew i wouldnt ask*